# In Osclass, can't call JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, osclass

In OsClass,
this is my code, from footer.php

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <div id="footer_1" class="col">
            <h1>location</h1>
            <ul>
                <form action="<?php echo osc_base_url(true); ?>" method="get" class="search" name="locat">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="search" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="sCity" name="sCity" value="" />
                    <li id="1" onclick="locat();"> mysore</li>
                    <li id="2" onclick="locat();">bhfgh</li>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript is, (placed in the same page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function locat()
    {
        var city = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(city);
    }   
</script>
```

Here, JS function is not working. It's gives

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
    onclick
```

Where is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<li id="1" onclick="locat(this);"> mysore</li>
```

and JS:

```
function locat(obj) {
    var city = $(obj).attr('id');
    alert(city);
}
```

Otherwise you execute `locat` in wrong context (`window` and not clicked element).

But anyway this is not right way to bind events since you are using jQuery. It could be:

```
 <li class="city" id="1">mysore</li>
 <li class="city" id="2">bhfgh</li>
```

and jQuery code for this structure:

```
$('.city').click(function() {
    var city = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(city);
});
```

would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Code that is run from onclick attribute, doesn't fire in context of node it is put on, hence "this" is undefined in locat function.

To fix it, you can replace this:

```
<li id="1" onclick="locat();"> mysore</li>
```

with this:

```
<li id="1" onclick="locat.call(this);"> mysore</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `form` object is overwriting your `locat` function (at least it is like that in Safari on Mac) - finally you'r trying to call the element not your function. Just change your function name and it should work, except couple other things. First of all `this` won't be element that you suppose to be, it will be `window` object as functions in onclick are called in default scope, not element's context. Second thing is a little advice - you should not start `{` from new line as of implicit semicolon insertion.